# Mysql_result() error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get pagination to work on my page, but running into a error:

`mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in`

I think I need to use a `mysqli` command but can't seem to figure it out.  Here is my code

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'vdb');
$per_page = 6;
$pages_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customers");

$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT cid, fname, lname,address, score  FROM customers");


while ($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $query_row['fname'] . '<br />';
}
if($pages >= 1)
{
    for($x=1; $x <= $pages; $x++)
    {
        echo '<a href="?page='.$x.'">' .$x.'</a>';
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Combining mysql and mysqli is always bad..

Comment: You're using mysqli* then do not use mysql* function ;)

Comment: If you're using mysql, use mysql. If you're using mysqli, use mysqli. Never shall the two meet.

Comment: Hi I know I'm jumping between the two, what would be a better solution for `mysql_result` because `mysqli_result` does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You are jumbling between `mysql` and `mysqli`

```
$pages_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customers"); // MySQLi

$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page); // MySQL
```

Comment: Hi I know I'm jumping between the two, what would be a better solution for `mysql_result` because `mysqli_result` does not exist

Answer (score 0):

There should be `mysqli_result` instead of `mysql_result`. Never mix them up and use just `mysqli_*` functions.

```
// line 3 of code above
$pages = ceil(mysqli_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);
                   ^^
```